# How can I bring a div over its parent div that has linear gradient as its mask-image?

Tags: css

```
.review-comment {
   position: relative;
   height: 6em;
   overflow: hidden;
   mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, black 75%, transparent);
   z-index: 0;
}

.read-more-container {
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

[I would like the "read more" link to appear "over" the linear gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RB0xX.png)

Comment: read more need to be outside the masked element

Comment: @TemaniAfif I was so tunnel visioned on the problem, thank you!!